# What is the Dedekind cut for 2?

Tags: real-analysis

I was watching a lecture on defining the reals. The professor named a set $\beta$ such that $\beta =\big\{ r\in Q:r<2 \big\}$ and he said that this is not a cut because it does not satisfy our third requirements of cuts, that there is no largest element, but this seems to be a mistake. Shouldn't this be a cut that defines 2? Since 2 is not included in the set it should work the same way that it does for 1 of the negative rationals, shouldn't it?

Comment: You're right, $\beta$ *does* have the property that there is no largest element.

Comment: I believe this is a mistake.  $\{r\in\Bbb Q:r<2\}$ has no largest element.

Comment: Perhaps it was a misreading of the lecture? $\{r\in\mathbb Q\mid r\leq 2\}$ was probably what the professor was saying.